# Fitting an exponential system

Tags: equation-solving, performance-tuning, mathematical-optimization, fitting, nonlinear

Consider the following system over a periodic array, where $1\leq j\leq n$,
$$
y_j= \sum_{k=0}^m  \frac{e^{-\sum_{|i|\leq k}(k-|i|)x_{j+i}}-e^{-\sum_{|i|\leq k}(k+1-|i|)x_{j+i}}}{\sum_{|i|\leq k} x_{j+i}}
$$
where $m= \lceil (n-3)/2 \rceil$ (to avoid variable repeats). Given data $\{y_j\}$, I want to estimate $\{x_j\}$ (non-negative). Is there any Mathematica function or package that could efficiently solve this?

**Some thoughts:** I have heard of quasi-Newton and Nelder-Mead methods, but I am wondering if there is already some code developed on this, to tackle a fitting problem like this one. What would be the best way to implement a numerical problem like this in Mathematica? Could something like `NonlinearModelFit` be useful here? Also, this is an example of the relatively [smooth data](https://justpaste.it/59qtt) ($n=2000$) I am dealing with, if it helps.

**Note:** If easier, I would also be happy with a non-periodic solution. To understand the difference, take $k=2$ and $j=1$, for example. We have
$$
\begin{aligned}
\text{Periodic: }&\sum_{|i|\leq k} x_{j+i}=x_{n-1}+x_n+x_1+x_2+x_3\\
\text{Non-periodic: }&\sum_{|i|\leq k} x_{j+i}=x_1+x_2+x_3
\end{aligned}
$$
Any ideas?

**My attempt:** Here is my attempt, which is quite slow for the entire data. Also, this is without the imposition of non-negativity of $\{x_i\}$

```
(*Define the given system*)
y[j_, x_List, n_] := 
 Sum[(Exp[-Sum[(k - Abs[i]) x[[Mod[j + i, n, 1]]], {i, -k, k}]] - 
     Exp[-Sum[(k + 1 - Abs[i]) x[[Mod[j + i, n, 1]]], {i, -k, k}]])/
   Sum[x[[Mod[j + i, n, 1]]], {i, -k, k}], {k, 0, n}]

(*Observed data*)
yObserved = data[[1 ;; 20]];(*Replace with your observed y values*)n =
  Length[yObserved];

(*Initial estimate for x values*)
x0 = ConstantArray[1, n];

(*Minimize the sum of squared residuals*)
minimizationFunction[x_List] := 
 Sum[(y[j, x, n] - yObserved[[j]])^2, {j, 1, n}]

stepNumber = 0;
solution = 
 FindMinimum[minimizationFunction[x], {x, x0}, 
  StepMonitor :> (stepNumber++;
    PrintTemporary["Iteration: ", stepNumber, ", Residuals: ", 
     minimizationFunction[x]])]

xEstimated = x /. solution[[2]];
```

Comment: The contents of "data," please.

Comment: @IAmANaïf See the link in "smooth data"

Comment: Oops! Thanks. I overlooked that/

Comment: I tried to answer your question. I put my answer up. Three other users used their powers to delete that answer. I spent several days determining what the problem was within your question. Your $y$ expression when fully expanded is large (six megabytes). It takes a long time to evaluate. The time for evaluation is on the order $n^2$. When I tried your $n$ is 20 small example using **FindMinimum** , it took on the order of a minute. A $n$ of 10,000 problem would take on the order of a week to do. There is no *magic" answer.

Comment: @IAmANaïf I appreciate your effort, thank you. I understand the complexity and computational demand of this problem. However, I still expect a local approximation to be achievable, and that is why I shared it here.

Answer (score 1):

First, this is not your method *at all*; although it does fit a definition of an exponential fit. Perhaps, you could cite a web resource that illustrates the method you intended.

The $\text{data}$ variable is from your aforementioned *smooth data* without modification. All the data is used herein.

The $\text{maxPower}$ affects the closeness of the fit.

```mma
n = Length[data]
log = MapThread[List, 
    {(N[#1/n] & ) /@ Range[0, n - 1], 
     Log /@ data}]; 
maxPower = 50
nDigits = Length[IntegerDigits[
    maxPower]]
vars = (Symbol[StringJoin @@ 
      Prepend[ToString /@ 
        IntegerDigits[#1, 10, 
         nDigits], "p"]] & ) /@ 
   Range[0, maxPower]
powers = (x^#1 & ) /@ Range[0, 
    maxPower]
expr = vars . powers
Block[{exponent}, 
  exponent = (vars /. FindFit[log, 
       expr, vars, x]) . powers; 
   ClearAll[y]; y = Function[x, 
     Evaluate[E^exponent]]]
Show[{Plot[y[i/n], {i, 0, 
     Length[data] - 1}, PlotStyle -> 
     Orange], ListPlot[data]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Computing root mean square residuals would not be difficult.

I agree that your data itself is not all that large, perhaps in the neighborhood of 16 KB. That is not what I said though. Unfortunately, your fully expanded, without evaluation, $y$ expression does run about 64 GB per index and that is a large amount of code to be evaluated. The growth of the effective $y$ expression grows on an order of $n^2$, where $n$ is the number of data points. Your methods are on the order of the complexity of naïve matrix inversion, which is on the order of $n^3$. Going from 20 to 2000 is a factor of a million. One second becomes about eleven days.

ChatGPT was not used in any way.

Comment: I have looked at your code and it is a nice fit, but, unless I misunderstood something, it does not really answer my question. My question is very simple: given the equation determining the relation between data $\{y_j\}$ and unknown variables $\{x_j\}$ I want to find an estimate for $\{x_j\}$ so that the equation is true, to some error. That is what I mean by fitting. Hope it is clear now! If your code gives $\{x_j\}$ that satisfy the equation, please clarify. Also, I do not understand what you mean by "your method". Thanks!

Comment: Having said that, it is expected that many kinds of fitting methods are achievable, simply by transforming the dataset (discrete Fourier transforms, for example). However, this is not what I am looking for. If, however, you can prove a relation between an easier fit and the main equation, so that $\{x_j\}$ still approximate the data through that equation to some error, that would be an interesting answer (I personally think that is the only way). Note also that the term "exponential fit" is, in this case, to be taken loosely (the equation involves exponentials).

Comment: @sam wolfe  "Your method" refers to that $y$ expression (perhaps what you call "main equation") which is very complex and is causing the slowness. Do you have a link to a web site that shows the basis and derivation of that $y$ expression?

Comment: This is the generalized version of [this problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4622582/expected-timing-of-an-activation-process), for non-constant rates $f_i$ ($x_i$ in this question).

Answer (score 0):

```
n = Length[data]
range = Ceiling[(n - 3)/2]
wanted = 25
m = Min[range, Max[0, wanted]]
d = Length[IntegerDigits[m]]
vars = (Symbol[StringJoin[Prepend[#1, "x"]]] & ) /@ 
   (ToString /@ IntegerDigits[#1, 10, d] & ) /@ Range[m]
wrap = Function[index, Mod[index, m, 1]]; 
y = Function[{j}, 
   Total[Table[(1/Sum[vars[[wrap[j + i]]], {i, -k, k}])*
      (E^(-Sum[(k - RealAbs[i])*vars[[wrap[j + i]]], 
          {i, -k, k}]) - E^(-Sum[(k + 1 - RealAbs[i])*
           vars[[wrap[j + i]]], {i, -k, k}])), {k, 0, m}]]]
Function[{j}, FullSimplify[
    Total[Table[(E^(-Sum[(k - RealAbs[i])*vars[[wrap[j + i]]], 
           {i, -k, k}]) - E^(-Sum[(k + 1 - RealAbs[i])*
            vars[[wrap[j + i]]], {i, -k, k}]))/
       Sum[vars[[wrap[j + i]]], {i, -k, k}], {k, 0, m}]]]]; 
Timing[expr = Total[Table[(y[j] - data[[j]])^2, {j, n}]]]
Timing[result = NMinimize[expr, vars]]
```

The wider the range (of propagation the slower the process. From my understanding of [Expected timing of an activation process](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4622582/expected-timing-of-an-activation-process) and a better understanding of formula at the top of your statement of the problem, I believe that you are trying to derive the propagation parameters. The output from a range of 25 is $$\{63.9531,\{2.66773\times 10^7,\{\text{x01}\to -0.0130553,\text{x02}\to -0.00660574,\text{x03}\to -0.00615878,\text{x04}\to -0.00610077,\text{x05}\to -0.00607452,\text{x06}\to -0.00604879,\text{x07}\to -0.00603599,\text{x08}\to -0.00601058,\text{x09}\to -0.0060006,\text{x10}\to -0.00598022,\text{x11}\to -0.00596845,\text{x12}\to -0.00595496,\text{x13}\to -0.00594078,\text{x14}\to -0.00592631,\text{x15}\to -0.00591097,\text{x16}\to -0.00589658,\text{x17}\to -0.00587923,\text{x18}\to -0.00586539,\text{x19}\to -0.00584332,\text{x20}\to -0.00582486,\text{x21}\to -0.00580145,\text{x22}\to -0.00577429,\text{x23}\to -0.00571453,\text{x24}\to -0.00526781,\text{x25}\to 0.00117529\}\}\}$$

Mathematica input format (last step reran so the timing is different):

```
{63.203125, {2.667734993144355*^7, 
   {x01 -> -0.013055299541910068, x02 -> -0.006605743167843227, 
    x03 -> -0.006158784075809141, x04 -> -0.006100765363784652, 
    x05 -> -0.006074519029737556, x06 -> -0.006048792662569355, 
    x07 -> -0.00603599147278341, x08 -> -0.006010576756960721, 
    x09 -> -0.006000604527684114, x10 -> -0.005980215418854892, 
    x11 -> -0.005968450719740911, x12 -> -0.005954958597652362, 
    x13 -> -0.0059407848911348995, 
    x14 -> -0.0059263085011297244, x15 -> -0.00591097293627474, 
    x16 -> -0.005896581125312389, x17 -> -0.00587923364074972, 
    x18 -> -0.005865386676229418, x19 -> -0.005843315260534448, 
    x20 -> -0.005824863710473156, x21 -> -0.005801447713342566, 
    x22 -> -0.005774285145486874, x23 -> -0.005714531103859852, 
    x24 -> -0.005267808848584054, 
    x25 -> 0.0011752901871872874}}}
```

Comment: Interesting approach. Keep in mind that I require $x_i$ to be positive. Is it possible to find a solution in this case? I will check this code a bit more in detail later, but thank you nonetheless!